# Concat string inside an object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I was wondering what is the clean way to concat a string inside an object?

```
public class Example
{
    public string name { get; set; }

}

public void BuildExample()
{
   Example x = new Example();
   x.name = "Hello";

   sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append(" children: [{");

   var parent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
   var output = string.Concat(parent.ToString(), sb);

 }
```

output

```
{"name":"Hello"} children: [{
```

desired output

```
{
 "name":"hello",
  children: [{
```

Comment: Why are you manually constructing JSON? If you need to do this to avoid creating classes, why not use anonymous objects? Or a dictionary? Or a dynamic expandoobject?

Comment: @John please see my previous thread :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723127/pass-strongly-type-object-to-list-to-create-new-json-structure

Comment: Your previous question doesn't make much sense to me, I'm afraid. Isn't building the tree simple? What makes it difficult?

Comment: @John Just finding it difficult to create the new structure based on the json output I currently have. If you look at the thread you should see the "desired output" and the current json I am working with and how best to implement it

Comment: Don't you just want [this](https://rextester.com/VIBIUL63694)? If it is, let me know and I'll add an answer to your other question.

Comment: @john I know string builder is bad practice as I tried to implement this with a strongly typed objects but when i got down to nested objects I hit a wall. Please feel free to add an answer to my other question. I am keen to understand how you could implement it. Still fairly new with json.net

Comment: look at this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonManually.htm

Comment: @John In terms of a column holding a dynamic item depending on type e.g. text or image how can I create this class outside of Section to be added in column?

Answer (score 1):

`children` needs to be an array property of your `Example` class to have `JsonConvert` generate your desired output.

```
public class Example
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string[] children { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: I understand this but I would like to use a stringbuilder (implementation reasons). I know I can build up json using strongly typed objects :)